# Bipartie Matching to form an Array

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am given a number from `1 to N` , and there are `M` relationship given in the form `a` and `b` where we can connect number `a` and `b`.
We have to form the valid array , A array is said to be valid if for any two consecutive indexes `A[i]  and A[i+1] is  one of the M relationship`

We have to construct a valid Array of Size `N`, it's always possible to construct that.

**Solution:** Make A Bipartite Graph of the following , but there is a loophole on this,

```
let N=6
M=6
1 2
2 3
1 3
4 5
5 6
3 4

So Bipartite Matching gives this:
Match[1]=2 
Match[2]=3 
Match[3]=1   // Here it form a Loop
Match[4]=5
Match[5]=6
```

So how to i print a valid Array of size `N` , since N can be very large so many loops can be formed  ? Is there any other solution ?

Another Example:

```
let N=6
M=6
1 3
3 5
2 5
5 1
4 2
6 4


  It's will form a loop  1->3->5->1
1 3 5 2 4 6
```

Comment: `A[i]  and A[i+1] is  one of the M relationship` seems to mean that basically your match is `Match[i] = i+1` for all i except the last. So you should have `Match[3] = 4`

Comment: @njzk2 it's not always like that updated the  question

Comment: Isn't this the NP-complete Hamiltonian cycle problem?

Comment: @NarendraModi `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1` is a bipartite graph, even though it has a cycle.

Comment: How large can `N` and `M` be? Are there any additional constraints? It's a Hamiltonian path problem without additional constraints.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz You should convert that to an answer.

Comment: @NarendraModi I agree with your answer, good solution. except that last element can point to the first or any other element .